# $front->dispatch() show error

Tags: zend-framework

I am using `$front->dispatch();`   Zendframework

but it show me the errors

> 'No default module defined for this application' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\traveda\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:391

can u plz guide me

Answer (score 0):

Have you set controller directory for your app?
    
    resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"